# How can I bind elements List of array

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have following code in ViewModel -

```
List<Class1> categories = new List<Class1>
Class1 ob1 = new Class1(){
    Heading = "H1",
    Commands = new VMCommand[]
    {
        new VMCommand("Command11", CanExecuteCommand11, ExecuteCommand11),
        new VMCommand("Command12", CanExecuteCommand12, ExecuteCommand12),
        new VMCommand("Command13", CanExecuteCommand13, ExecuteCommand13),
        new VMCommand("Command14", CanExecuteCommand14, ExecuteCommand14)
    }
categories.Add(ob1);
Class1 ob2 = new Class1(){
    Heading = "H2",
    Commands = new VMCommand[]
    {
        new VMCommand("Command21", CanExecuteCommand21, ExecuteCommand21),
        new VMCommand("Command22", CanExecuteCommand22, ExecuteCommand22),
        new VMCommand("Command23", CanExecuteCommand23, ExecuteCommand23),
        new VMCommand("Command24", CanExecuteCommand24, ExecuteCommand24)
    }
categories.Add(ob2);
```

I am getting categories in Xaml. I want to bing a List with all the Commands from all categories.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a property or method which extracts all the commands and then bind to that. I haven't compiled this, but you should be able to do something like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<VMCommand> AllCommands
{
    return new ObservableCollection(categories.SelectMany(x => x.Commands));    
}
```

Comment: I dont wanna change ViwModel. I got a Hint - I tried categories/Commands. It is giving all the commands of first group. Can you explore it??